# How to make a dictionary from lists

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to add this two list into a dictionary

```
list_id= ['2000391314791P', '2000391314715P', '2000383032443P', '2000387592776P', '2000391314760P', '2000387592813P', '2000383032511P', '2000391314784P', '2000387592738P', '2000387592806P', '2000387592769P', '2000387592790P', '2000387592752P', '2000391314746P', '2000391314777P', '2000391314753P', '2000391314814P', '2000387592783P', '2000383032429P', '2000383032467P', 'MPM00043444018', 'MPM00040888375']
```

```
productos= ['APPLE MACBOOK PRO 13,3" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 256GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,6" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 8NUC) / 8GB RAM / 256GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,3" / CHIP M1 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 7NUC) / 8GB RAM / 256GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 16" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 16NUC) / 16GB RAM / 1TB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,6" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 14NUC) / 16GB RAM / 512GB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 13,3" / CHIP M1 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 8NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 13,3" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 256GB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 16" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 16NUC) / 16GB RAM / 512GB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 16NUC) / 16GB RAM / 1TB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 16" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 16NUC) / 16GB RAM / 1TB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 16NUC) / 16GB RAM / 1TB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 16" / CHIP M1 MAX (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 32NUC) / 32GB RAM / 1TB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,6" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / AZUL MEDIANOCHE', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,6" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / BLANCO ESTELAR', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,6" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 13,3" / CHIP M2 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 10NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 16" / CHIP M1 PRO (CPU 10NUC Y GPU 16NUC) / 16GB RAM / 512GB SSD / COLOR PLATA', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,3" / CHIP M1 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 7NUC) / 8GB RAM / 256GB SSD / COLOR ORO', 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,3" / CHIP M1 (CPU 8NUC Y GPU 8NUC) / 8GB RAM / 512GB SSD / GRIS ESPACIAL', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SILVER', 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY']
```

```
datos = { id_: { 'name': i for i in productos}   for id_ in lista_id}
```

```
{'2000391314791P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314715P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000383032443P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592776P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314760P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592813P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000383032511P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314784P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592738P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592806P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592769P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592790P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592752P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314746P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314777P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314753P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314814P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000387592783P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000383032429P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000383032467P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 'MPM00043444018': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 'MPM00040888375': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'}}
```

I need one id for one product not the same product, like this:

```
{'2000391314791P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK PRO 14.2 1TB M1 PRO 10C GPU 16C SPACE GREY'},
 '2000391314715P': {'nombre': 'APPLE MACBOOK AIR 13,6 CHIP M2 CPU 8NUC Y GPU 8NUC 8GB RAM  256GB SSD COLOR PLATA'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `list_id` and `productos` are in the same order and have the same number of items, you can simply use enumerate in your dictionary comprehension:

```
datos = {id: productos[i] for i, id in enumerate(list_id)}
```

I hope that's what you were looking for.